# Conditional include based on filename

Tags: msbuild

I want msbuild to include a package only if this is not a certain file, namely bla.csproj. Something similar to the line below. What is the correct syntax?

`<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" Condition="%(!FileName.Contains('bla.csproj'))" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it:

```
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectName)' != 'bla'" />
```